# Where should I go to find the TensorRT-llm/benchmark .json data of baichuan2-7b?

Tags: dataset, benchmarking, tensorrt

I want to test TensorRt-LLM benchmark recently. When I see its' readme in github, I found that if you want to test benchmark/inflight batching, you should prepare dataset first. I haven readed the code of /tensorrt_llm/benchmarks/cpp/utils/prepare_real_data.py, I found I should use .json data as input first. But I am not very familiar with it, I don't konw where can get the .json data of baichuan2-7b....

I want to get the .json data of baichuan2-7b input